# How to count amount of processes using Batch file (.bat)

Tags: batch-file, process, count

For example, I want to count the amount of processes with the name "chrome.exe". How can I do that using batch file and show it using ECHO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%# in ('qprocess^|find /i /c /n "chrome"') do (
    set number=%%#
)

echo number of chromes: %number%
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not working. Cmd starts and closes... Do you know why?

Comment: @Thyoity - set `PAUSE` at the end or call it through the command prompt.

Answer (score 3):

```
tasklist|find /i /c "chrome.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the output like

No Process exists for my id
number of chromes: 0
Press any key to continue

But if i check the task manager, there are lot of chrome.exe processes running.